# Two supplemental search engine on the same page?

Tags: php, wordpress, search-engine

I am currently working on a *search result page* and I need to have 2 search engine on my page. Both will work with the same keywords but will look for different type of post. The first engine will only search for products(ie: books) and the other engine will search for pages (ie: author). I use **searchWP**' **supplemental search engine** and I can show both of them in different way in the same page.

The problem is they share the same total results. If I have 3 page of results for *pages* but only 2 for *products* and I want to see page 3 it will change to page 3 for both of them. This cause *products* to display "no results" kind of message instead of his last results.

How can I resolve this problem?

**EDIT**

The code I am using is something like this : https://gist.github.com/jchristopher/8905945#file-gistfile1-php . At line 17 I call *product*. I call *pages* on the same line but on a duplication version.

For the output I use block-grid (Foundation 5) for my *products* and a normal list for my *pages*

**EDIT**

My problem seems to be with my pagination. It look like when I create my second pagination (the one for *author*) it override the first one. I figure out how to just change the author' pagination but book' stay at page 1.

https://gist.github.com/Alcalt/6094632df79e16d49280 
This is a function that work perfectly when you only have 1 pagination but I can't find a way to make it work with more than 1 without having the next pagination overriding the last.

Comment: Please provide a code example of what you are using currently. Maybe an example of expected results too. This question is really general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to make my pagination' function work. I just add *if* conditions to be able to know which search engine I was currently using and with the results I set my variables.

https://gist.github.com/Alcalt/c5d0961fd244eee978d4